# Multiclass classification confidence score using multiclass classification using predict_proba of SGDclassifier

Tags: probability, logistic-regression, prediction, multiclass-classification, sgd

I am using Logistic regression in SGDClassifier to perform multi-class classification of ~10k category.
To get confidence score for predicted result I am using predict_proba function.
But I am getting prediction probability value of  0.00026091,0.00049697,0.00019632 for both correct and wrong prediction.

Please suggest the way to normalize the score so that I can consider result by filtering the probability value

Answer (score 0):

If the probability values of all classes are very low, it might mean, that your classifier has a hard time to classify the samples. You might want to do some feature engineering or try another model.
To normalize the values, have a look at scikit-learn MinMaxScaler. This will scale the data to numbers between 0 and 1. But as I said, if the probability for all values is very low, you wont get a good classification result.
Hope that helps